# Como poner las respuestas en orden descendente y ascendente

Tags: c

Por favor, necesito ayuda con este problema:

1- Necesito un programa que dado 2 número por el usuario, muestre los números comprendidos entre ellos en orden ascendente y también en orden descendente en lenguaje C

Yo ya hice el programa que muestra los números comprendidos que da el usuario pero no se como poner que de las respuestas en orden descendente y ascendente. Aquí el código:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n1, n2, numero;
  printf("\n Introduzca el n1: ", 163);
  scanf("%d", &n1);
  printf("\n Introduzca el n2: ", 163);
  scanf("%d", &n2);
  printf("\n ");
  if (n1 <= n2)
    do {
      printf("%d ", n1);
      n1++;
    } while (n1 <= n2);
  for (numero = n1; numero >= n2; numero = numero - 1)
    printf("%d \n", numero);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo siento pero no hacemos tareas, si puedes agrega lo que has intentado para que saber cual es tu problema con mas exacitud y para poder ayudarte

Comment: #include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, numero;

    printf( "\n   Introduzca el n1: ", 163 );
    scanf( "%d", &n1 );
    printf( "\n   Introduzca el n2: ", 163 );
    scanf( "%d", &n2 );
    printf( "\n   " );

    if ( n1 <= n2 )
        do
        {
            printf( "%d ", n1);
            n1++;
        } while ( n1 <= n2 );

        for(numero=n1;numero>=n2;numero=numero-1)
            printf("%d \n", numero);
    return 0;
}

Comment: lo que no se como hacer es como hacer que muestre el resultado en orden ascendente y descendente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un ciclo `for` basa para mostrar los resultados de la forma que quieras. El ciclo `for` nos ayuda a iterar n veces según las condiciones que le pasemos. Para poder definir el inicio y fin del ciclo primero ordenaremos los datos,donde `n1` siempre tendrá el menor número y `n2` el mayor, eso lo podemos lograr con un `if`.

```c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main() { 
  int n1, n2, numero;
  printf( "Introduzca el n1: ");
  scanf( "%d", &n1 ); 
  printf( "\n Introduzca el n2: ");
  scanf( "%d", &n2 ); 
  printf( "\n" );
  if(n1>n2){
    int aux = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = aux;
  }
  printf("de forma ascendente\n");
  //mostramos de forma ascendene 
  for(int i=n1; i<n2; i++){
    printf("%i\n", i);
  }
  printf("de forma descendente\n");
  //mostramosde forma descendente
  for(int j=n2; j>n1; j--){
    printf("%i\n", j);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Si no e importa mucho la forma en como se muestre la salida entonces podemos usar un solo ciclo `for` con 2 condiciones.

```c
//los 2 ultimos ciclos for los reemplazamos por esto
  for(int i=n1, j=n2; i<n2 && j>n1; i++,j--){
    printf("n1= %i\n", i);
    printf("n2= %i\n",j);
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con la explicacion quede entendiendo, de verdad se lo agradezco :)

Comment: De nada, recuerda que puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta que más e haya servido :D

Answer (score 0):

**Generar secuencia a partir de 2 números con opción de orden ascendente y descendente**

Hola, compartiré una manera de lograr el objetivo que esperas de programa en C usando condicionales y el bucle `while`. Aquí el código y luego la explicación:

```
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
 int n1, n2, orden;
 printf( "\n Introduzca el n1: ", 163 );
 scanf( "%d", &n1 );
 printf( "\n Introduzca el n2: ", 163 );
 scanf( "%d", &n2 );
 printf( "\n Introduzca 1 para ordenar de forma Ascendente o 0 para Descendente: ");
 scanf( "%d", &orden );
 //
if(n1 < n2){
    /**/
    if(orden){ 
        printf("Has elegido orden Ascendente\n");
        printf("%i\n ",n1);
        while(n1 < n2){
            n1++;
            printf("%i\n ",n1);
         }
        }else{
            printf("Has elegido orden Descendente\n");
            printf("%i\n ",n2);
            while(n1 < n2){
            n2--;
            printf("%i\n ",n2);}
        }
    /**/
    }else{
    /**/
        if(!orden){ 
        printf("Has elegido orden Descendente\n");
        printf("%i\n ",n1);
        while(n1 > n2){
            n1--;
            printf("%i\n ",n1);
         }
        }else{
            printf("Has elegido orden Ascendente\n");
            printf("%i\n ",n2);
            while(n1 > n2){
            n2++;
            printf("%i\n ",n2);}
        }
    /**/
    }
 
return 0; }
```

**Explicación**

Las variables `n1` y `n2` reciben los números para generar la secuencia. La variable orden guardara un 1 o un 0 como valores lógico para generar el orden ascendentes o descendentes. Los condicionales `if` y `else` permite elegir el bucle `while` adecuado para los casos en que `n1 > n2` o `n2 > n1`. Así generar la secuencia en el orden deseado sin problema. Este código es una idea, se podría refactorizar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo, agradezco que me haya explicado, Muchas gracias de verdad